# ARKit 4 | Export Point Cloud

Tags: arkit, metal, metalkit, realitykit

I was playing around with [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/visualizing_a_point_cloud_using_scene_depth) app that apple released. When I sweep my iPad Pro around the room multiple times a dense point cloud is displayed on the screen. How can I save the raw data from the Metal Buffer where I guess the point cloud raw data resides (correct me if I'm wrong). I want to save the coordinates, normal and color for each point.